# Make a boxplot without whiskers

Tags: r, boxplot

I have made box-plots for the onset values of three different groups using the box-plot function in R like so:

```
boxplot(onset ~ group, data = pulse.dat, range = 0, col = "lightblue")
```

However, I want to see how the data looks without the range, so I want to create a box-plot without the whiskers. I also wouldn't mind any kind of graph as long as it displays the median, 25th and 75th quartile for each of the 3 groups.

Does anyone know how I can do this in R?

Comment: "Quantiles" or "percentiles", not quartiles. And you should realize that `boxplot` is not plotting the 25th and 75th quantiles. See `?boxplot.stats`

Comment: for python users who have the same question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314963/1316649

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under boxplot pars...

```
 d <- rnorm(1:100, 100, 10)
 boxplot(d, whisklty = 0, staplelty = 0)
```

`whisklty` gets rid of the lines or whiskers

`staplelty` gets rid of the ends or staples