# R boxplot: How to customize the appearance of the box-and-whisker plots (e.g., remove lines or borders, change symbol of outliers)

Tags: r, shapes, boxplot, appearance, linestyle

Today, I was wondering how to customize the appearance of the box-and-whisker plots. E.g., I wanted to remove the line around the box. However, the problem is, that the `border` argument changes the color of all lines of the box-and-whisker plots simultaneously. So, if one has the great idea to set `border = "white"` then the whiskers are also going to “disappear” and you have a white line representing your median.

As I could not find a solution on the internet dealing with exactly my problem, I fiddled around a little and figured some mighty settings which seem to be nearly undocumented as a whole. These settings allow you to customize the appearance of your box-and-whisker plots to a large extend. I know, some of the features have already been unveiled on stackoverflow (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869343/make-a-boxplot-without-whiskers-in-r)). However, I could not find a complete documentation. Thus, this post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For complete documentation you should look at `?bxp` (linked from the `...` description in `?boxplot`, and in the "See Also" in `?boxplot`, and in the `pars` description in `?boxplot`.). It documents that `outpch` can change the shape of the outliers (though `pch` works fine too). It also has `boxlty`, `boxlwd`, `boxcol` and `boxfill` for the box, and many others for the whiskers, the staples, median line...

Comment: Well, I missed that small `bxp` link. It would have had all the information. Thank you!

Answer (score 49):

In order to customize the appearance of the box-and-whisker plots, you have to change the `med[…]`, `box[…]`, `whisk[…]`, or `staple[…]` argument for adjusting the line settings, or the `out[…]` argument for outliers.

[image]

`[…]` needs to be replaced by one of the following line or point arguments:

Arguments for the appearance of line elements (for more information see `?par` in R):

- `lty`: line style (e.g.,`= 0` to remove the line,`= 1` for solid line)
- `lwd`: line width
- `col`: line color

Arguments for the appearance of outliers (for more information see `?points` in R):

- `pch`: symbol style
- `lwd`: line width
- `cex`: size of symbol
- `col`: color
- `bg`: background color

So, here is an **example** of how the above boxplot might be "customized":

```
boxplot( … , medcol = "red", boxlty = 0, whisklty = 1, staplelwd = 4, outpch = 8, outcex = 3)
```

This leads to the following boxplot:

[image]