# Customize colors for boxplot with highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, colors, boxplot, r-highcharter

I have boxplots on highcharter and I would like to customize both the

- Fill color
- Border color

Here is my code

```
df = data.frame(cbind(categ = rep(c('a','b','c','d')),value = rnorm(1000)))

hcboxplot(var = df$categ, x = as.numeric(df$value)) %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column")  %>% 
  hc_colors(c("#203d7d","#a0a0ed","#203d7e","#a0a0ad"))
```

The hc_colors works only if I put `var2` instead of `var` but then the box plot are shrunken...

Comment: Would you also be open for other solutions than highcharter?

Comment: Depends on the solution, I would like a plot that draw itself when you open it like in highcharter. I already know how to do it in ggplot or plotly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple functions to do some stuff with highcharts and boxplots. It will let you color each boxplot and fill it accordingly, and then inject new graphical parameters according to the Highcharts API, should you desire.

Check it out:

```
## Boxplots Data and names, note the data index (0,1,2) is the first number in the datum
series<- list(
  list(
    name="a",
    data=list(c(0,1,2,3,4,5))
  ),
  list(
    name="b",
    data=list(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

  ),
  list(
    name="c",
    data=list(c(2,3,4,5,6,7))

  )
)

# Graphical attribute to be set: fillColor.
# Make the colors for the box fill and then also the box lines (make them match so it looks pretty)
cols<- viridisLite::viridis(n= length(series2), alpha = 0.5) # Keeping alpha in here! (for box fill)
cols2<- substr(cols, 0,7) # no alpha, pure hex truth, for box lines 

gen_key_vector<-function(variable, num_times){
  return(rep(variable, num_times))
} 

kv<- gen_key_vector(variable = "fillColor", length(series)) 

# Make a function to put stuff in the 'series' list, requires seq_along to be used since x is the list/vector index tracker

add_variable_to_series_list<- function(x, series_list, key_vector, value_vector){
  base::stopifnot(length(key_vector) == length(value_vector))
  base::stopifnot(length(series_list) == length(key_vector))
  series_list[[x]][length(series_list[[x]])+1]<- value_vector[x]
  names(series_list[[x]])[length(series_list[[x]])]<- key_vector[x]
  return(series_list[[x]])
}
## Put the extra stuff in the 'series' list
series2<- lapply(seq_along(series), function(x){ add_variable_to_series_list(x = x, series_list = series, key_vector = kv, value_vector = cols) })


hc<- highcharter::highchart() %>%
  highcharter::hc_chart(type="boxplot", inverted=FALSE) %>%
  highcharter::hc_title(text="This is a title") %>%
  highcharter::hc_legend(enabled=FALSE) %>%
  highcharter::hc_xAxis(type="category", categories=c("a", "b", "c"), title=list(text="Some x-axis title")) %>%
  highcharter::hc_add_series_list(series2) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(
    marker = list(
      symbol = "circle"
    ),
    grouping=FALSE
  )) %>%
  highcharter::hc_colors(cols2) %>%
  highcharter::hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)
hc
```

This probably could be adjusted to work with a simple dataframe, but I think it will get you what you want for right now without having to do too much extra work. Also, maybe look into `list_parse` or `list_parse2' from`highcharter`...it could probably help with building out the`series` object..I still need to look into that.

***Edit:***

I have expanded the example to make it work with a regular DF. As per some follow up questions, the colors are set using the `viridis` palette inside the `make_highchart_boxplot_with_colored_factors` function. If you want to allow your own palette and colors, you could expose those arguments and just include them as parameters inside the function call. The expanded example borrows how to add outliers from the `highcharter` library (albeit in a hacky way) and then builds everything else up from scratch. Hopefully this helps clarify my previous answer. Please note, I could probably also clean up the `if` condition to make it a little more brief, but I kept it verbose for illustrative purposes.

***Double Edit: You can now specify a vector of colors for each level of the factor variable***

```
library(highcharter)
library(magrittr)
library(viridisLite)

df = data.frame(cbind(categ = rep(c('a','b','c','d')),value = rnorm(1000)))
df$value<- base::as.numeric(df$value)


add_variable_to_series_list<- function(x, series_list, key_vector, value_vector){
  base::stopifnot(length(key_vector) == length(value_vector))
  base::stopifnot(length(series_list) == length(key_vector))
  series_list[[x]][length(series_list[[x]])+1]<- value_vector[x]
  names(series_list[[x]])[length(series_list[[x]])]<- key_vector[x]
  return(series_list[[x]])
}


# From highcharter github pages:
hc_add_series_bwpout = function(hc, value, by, ...) {
  z = lapply(levels(by), function(x) {
    bpstats = boxplot.stats(value[by == x])$stats
    outliers = c()
    for (y in na.exclude(value[by == x])) {
      if ((y < bpstats[1]) | (y > bpstats[5]))
        outliers = c(outliers, list(which(levels(by)==x)-1, y))
    }
    outliers
  })
  hc %>%
    hc_add_series(data = z, type="scatter", ...)
}


gen_key_vector<-function(variable, num_times){
  return(rep(variable, num_times))
} 
gen_boxplot_series_from_df<- function(value, by,...){
  value<- base::as.numeric(value)
  by<- base::as.factor(by)
  box_names<- levels(by)
  z=lapply(box_names, function(x) {
    boxplot.stats(value[by==x])$stats
  })
  tmp<- lapply(seq_along(z), function(x){
    var_name_list<- list(box_names[x])
    #tmp0<- list(names(df)[x])
    names(var_name_list)<- "name"
    index<- x-1
    tmp<- list(c(index,  z[[x]]))
    tmp<- list(tmp)
    names(tmp)<- "data"
    tmp_out<- c(var_name_list, tmp)
    #tmp<- list(tmp)
    return(tmp_out)

  })
  return(tmp)
}
# Usage: 
#series<- gen_boxplot_series_from_df(value = df$total_value, by=df$asset_class)


## Boxplot function:
make_highchart_boxplot_with_colored_factors<- function(value, by, chart_title="Boxplots",
                                                       chart_x_axis_label="Values", show_outliers=FALSE,
                                                       boxcolors=NULL, box_line_colors=NULL){
  by<- as.factor(by)
  box_names_to_use<- levels(by)
  series<- gen_boxplot_series_from_df(value = value, by=by)
  if(is.null(boxcolors)){
    cols<- viridisLite::viridis(n= length(series), alpha = 0.5) # Keeping alpha in here! (COLORS FOR BOXES ARE SET HERE)
  } else {
    cols<- boxcolors
  }
  if(is.null(box_line_colors)){
    if(base::nchar(cols[[1]])==9){
      cols2<- substr(cols, 0,7) # no alpha, pure hex truth, for box lines 
    } else {
      cols2<- cols
    }

  } else {
    cols2<- box_line_colors
  }

  # Injecting value 'fillColor' into series list
  kv<- gen_key_vector(variable = "fillColor", length(series)) 
  series2<- lapply(seq_along(series), function(x){ add_variable_to_series_list(x = x, series_list = series, key_vector = kv, value_vector = cols) })

  if(show_outliers == TRUE){
    hc<- highcharter::highchart() %>%
      highcharter::hc_chart(type="boxplot", inverted=FALSE) %>%
      highcharter::hc_title(text=chart_title) %>%
      highcharter::hc_legend(enabled=FALSE) %>%
      highcharter::hc_xAxis(type="category", categories=box_names_to_use, title=list(text=chart_x_axis_label)) %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_series_list(series2) %>%
      hc_add_series_bwpout(value = value, by=by, name="Outliers") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(
        marker = list(
          symbol = "circle"
        ),
        grouping=FALSE
      )) %>%
      highcharter::hc_colors(cols2) %>%
      highcharter::hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)

  } else{
    hc<- highcharter::highchart() %>%
      highcharter::hc_chart(type="boxplot", inverted=FALSE) %>%
      highcharter::hc_title(text=chart_title) %>%
      highcharter::hc_legend(enabled=FALSE) %>%
      highcharter::hc_xAxis(type="category", categories=box_names_to_use, title=list(text=chart_x_axis_label)) %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_series_list(series2) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(
        marker = list(
          symbol = "circle"
        ),
        grouping=FALSE
      )) %>%
      highcharter::hc_colors(cols2) %>%
      highcharter::hc_exporting(enabled=TRUE)
  }
  hc
}
# Usage:
tst_box<- make_highchart_boxplot_with_colored_factors(value = df$value, by=df$categ, chart_title = "Some Title", chart_x_axis_label = "Some X Axis", show_outliers = TRUE)
tst_box

# Custom Colors:
custom_colors_with_alpha_in_hex<- paste0(gplots::col2hex(sample(x=colors(), size = length(unique(df$categ)), replace = FALSE)), "80")
tst_box2<- make_highchart_boxplot_with_colored_factors(value = df$value, by=df$categ, chart_title = "Some Title",
                                                      chart_x_axis_label = "Some X Axis",
                                                      show_outliers = TRUE, boxcolors = custom_colors_with_alpha_in_hex)
tst_box2

tst_box3<- make_highchart_boxplot_with_colored_factors(value = df$value, by=df$categ, chart_title = "Some Title",
                                                                 chart_x_axis_label = "Some X Axis",
                                                                 show_outliers = TRUE, boxcolors = custom_colors_with_alpha_in_hex, box_line_colors = "black")
tst_box3
```

I hope this helps, please let me know if you have any more questions. I'm happy to try to help as best I can. 
-nate

Comment: I got what you did for the border colors, but i don't really understand how to change the fill color, I have everything filled in black when I test your code

Comment: Do you have viridis installed?

Comment: Yes I checked, it is installed, still filled in black :(

Comment: Even with the *edited* code? Also, I mis-spoke when I said to install `virids`. I should have said `viridisLite`

Comment: Seems to work perfectly now, thanks you very much !

Comment: Only one thing is not working though : the colour of the outliers points

Comment: Yeah, that is still something I am trying to work on. I spent a couple hours figuring out/experimenting with how to build out the data. I got very close, but my data ends up being quoted as characters when I try to add in different sets of outliers. I think it is a problem with the `toJSON` method I think gets used in the `htmlwidgets` package...`toJSON` will generate quoted items from a list unless they come from a `dataframe`...For this reason, I get something like `{data: [["2,10"], ["3,5"]]}` when I try to convert to proper JSON. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f2z9tLrs/

Answer (score 1):

API for styling **fillColor**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.fillColor

And for **"Border color"**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.color

Pure JavaScript example of how to style and define points: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6tud3fgx

And R code:

```
library(highcharter)
df = data.frame(cbind(categ = rep(c('a','b','c','d', 'e')),value = rnorm(1000)))
hcboxplot(var = df$categ, x = as.numeric(df$value)) %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column", events = list(
    load = JS("function() {
        var chart = this;
        chart.series[0].points[2].update({
          color: 'red'
        })
        chart.series[0].points[4].update({
          x: 4,
          low: 600,
          q1: 700,
          median: 800,
          q3: 900,
          high: 1000,
          color: 'orange'
        })
      }")
  ))  %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(boxplot = list(
    fillColor = '#F0F0E0',
    lineWidth = 2,
    medianColor = '#0C5DA5',
    medianWidth = 3,
    stemColor = '#A63400',
    stemDashStyle = 'dot',
    stemWidth = 1,
    whiskerColor = '#3D9200',
    whiskerLength = '20%',
    whiskerWidth = 3,
    color = 'black'
  ))  %>% 
  hc_colors(c("#203d7d","#a0a0ed","#203d7e","#a0a0ad"))
```

Comment: From my side I indeed have the custom colors but the same for each box.

Comment: My answer is just an example. I changed colors for specific points (points[2] and points[4]). Nothing stops you to change the colors for the whole series (each box) using chart.series[0].update({...})

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no `highcharter` answer yet, I give you at least a base solution.

First, your definition of the data frame is somewhat flawed, rather do:

```
dat <- data.frame(categ=c('a','b','c','d'), value=rnorm(1000))
```

Now, using `boxplot` is quite straightforward. `border` option colors your borders. With option `col` you also could color the fills.

```
boxplot(value ~ categ, dat, border=c("#203d7d","#a0a0ed","#203d7e","#a0a0ad"), pars=list(outpch=16))
```

***Gives***

[image]

***Note:*** See [this nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28890111/6574038) for further customizations.