# Can I remove whiskers and outliers from Boxplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

Some people find it confusing with whiskers and outliers in a Boxplot.
Is it possible to remove those from the Boxplot in Seaborn?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the outliers by setting `showfliers=False` and remove whiskers by setting `whis=0`.

Comment: Where in the code? Please upload as code sample